# Can't direct internet through a shadowsocks server

Tags: networking, ubuntu, proxy

I have Ubuntu 14.04.

This is `config.json` file including configurations of my friend's server running shadowsocks:

```
{
    "server":"ip address",
    "server_port":23,
    "local_port":1234,
    "password":"password",
    "timeout":600,
    "method":"aes-256-cfb"
}
```

I do `sslocal -c config.json` and successfully connect to the server.

Now for instance I can make it work with `google-chrome` using the following command: `google-chrome --proxy-server="socks5://127.0.0.1:1234" --host-resolver-rules="MAP * 0.0.0.0 , EXCLUDE localhost"`

The question is how can I make the whole internet connection to go through that server first. So that every single application can use it by default. Something you can activate and deactivate simply.

Things I tried and failed:

Using `tsocks` -> [`tsocks`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/532375/launch-program-through-shadowsocks)

Using `iptables` as `sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:1234` -> [this thread](http://adminsgoodies.com/configuring-ubuntu-for-global-socks5-proxy/)

Using System Settings -> Network -> Network Proxy along with `dconf-tools` to exclude hosts ->[this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70245/how-do-i-make-the-system-wide-proxy-settings-bypass-the-proxy-for-local-addresse)